# php Eclipse console output

Tags: php, eclipse, facebook, debugging

I'm trying to get php debug output to the console window in Eclipse but everything I have tried (echo, print) gets output to the web page. Any ideas?

Thanks

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write a command line program in PHP that will be running outside of a web context (e.g. not using Apache, run as a script from the command line)? If so, you could try debugging as a "PHP Script" (see http://www.jansch.nl/2009/05/03/debugging-parameters-for-cli-apps-using-eclipse-pdt/). Either way you will probably want to setup something like xdebug for debugging: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf

Comment: I writing a Facebook web app using the PDT toolset and would like to log runtime conditions into either the console or debug output windows in Eclipse.

Comment: Watch this around the 4:32 mark - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlHUCAf7oSk&feature=related - this was for a website, but it can do PHP scripts as well. Does that solve you problem?

Comment: Yep, this helps. It's not what I expected by I am getting information in the console window.